# Listen to a websocket and print the results to console

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, websocket

I am using `node.js` and would like to listen to a websocket which I opened in server.ts using:

```
import * as express   from 'express';
import * as http      from 'http';
import * as WebSocket from 'ws';

const app       = express();
const server    = http.createServer();
const ws_server = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

/**
    @Instructions: 
        1. on console run:  ts-node server.ts
        2. Navigate to chrome-extension://pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo/index.html and set URL to 

*/
ws_server.on('connection', (ws: WebSocket) => {

    // connection is up, add simple event:
    ws.on('message', (message: string) => {

        console.log('received: ' + message);
        ws.send(`hello, you sent -> ${message}`);

    });

    // send feedback to incoming connection
    ws.send('Hi there, I am a websocket server from server.ts');

});


server.listen(8999, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Now in `app.ts` I have this:

```
import * as express   from 'express';
import * as http      from 'http'   ;
import * as WebSocket from 'ws'     ;
import * as net       from 'net'    ;


// declare instance of web application
const app = express();

// home page
app.get('/', (req, res) => 
        res.send(`hello world from app.ts with rand num: ${Math.floor(Math.random()*100)}`)
    );

// .... I would like to listen to port 8999 and log the information to console, as well as
// upate the front end in real time

// start the app
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("web app listening on port 3000"));
```

what is the library to use for listening to port `8999`?

Comment: What's the question?  Your first block of code already listens on port 8999.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry I meant can I subscribe the process spawned in the first process, so that on subscription I can print the message sent by the first process to console.

Comment: I still have no idea what the question is.  What does "subscribe the process spawned in the first process" mean?  I have no idea.  You need to use more words to describe what you want help with.